# Проблема с erode и dilation

Tags: python, изображения, opencv, python-2.7

Привет. Мне нужно применить оператор dilate из cv2. Но такое ощущение, что он перепутан с erode, поскольку при использовании dilate границы утончаются, а при использовании erode наоборот, границы утолщаются. По логике же должен наблюдаться обратный эффект.

Пример исходного изображения:
[image: Исходное изображение]

Пример dilate-изображения:
[image: dilate-изображение]]

Пример erode-изображения:
[image: erode-изображение]

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким багом? Или же я чего-то не допонимаю?

Comment: Пытался понять, почему Гарри Поттеру пишут какую-то юридическую дребедень. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инвертируйте картинку :) dilate расширяет границы белого, erode сужает.

Цитата из [документации](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html):

> Чтобы лучше понять идею и избежать возможного недопонимания, в этом примере мы
>   инвертировали изображение, чтобы буква была белым объектом. Мы сделали
>   два расширения (dilation) с прямоугольным структурным элементом 3*3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]